# How to insert an empty column after each column in an existing dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe that looks as follows

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"A":[1,2,3,4], 
"B":[3,4,5,6], 
"C":[2,3,4,5]})
```

I would like to insert an empty column (with type string) after each existing column in the dataframe, such that the output looks like

```
    A  col1 B   col2    C   col3
0   1   NaN 3   NaN     2   NaN
1   2   NaN 4   NaN     3   NaN
2   3   NaN 5   NaN     4   NaN
3   4   NaN 6   NaN     5   NaN
```

Answer (score 5):

Actually there's a much more simple way thanks to [`reindex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html):

```
df.reindex([x for i, c in enumerate(df.columns, 1) for x in (c, f'col{i}')], axis=1)
```

Result:

```
   A  col1  B  col2  C  col3
0  1   NaN  3   NaN  2   NaN
1  2   NaN  4   NaN  3   NaN
2  3   NaN  5   NaN  4   NaN
3  4   NaN  6   NaN  5   NaN
```

---

Here's the other more complicated way:

```
import numpy as np

df.join(pd.DataFrame(np.empty(df.shape, dtype=object), columns=df.columns + '_sep')).sort_index(axis=1)

   A A_sep  B B_sep  C C_sep
0  1  None  3  None  2  None
1  2  None  4  None  3  None
2  3  None  5  None  4  None
3  4  None  6  None  5  None
```

Answer (score 1):

This solution worked for me: 
`merged = pd.concat([myDataFrame, pd.DataFrame(columns= [' '])], axis=1)`

Answer (score 0):

This is what you can do:

```
for count in range(len(df.columns)):
    df.insert(count*2+1, str('col'+str(count+1)), 'NaN')

print(df)
```

Output:

```
   A col1  B col2  C col3
0  1  NaN  3  NaN  2  NaN
1  2  NaN  4  NaN  3  NaN
2  3  NaN  5  NaN  4  NaN
3  4  NaN  6  NaN  5  NaN
```